# jQuery countdown timer

Tags: jquery

Currently i have this code

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#hideMsg').fadeOut('fast'); }, 2000);
```

is it possible for me to put countdown timer for 2 seconds?

Like

```
<div id="hideMsg">
The entry you posted not valid.
This Box will Close In 2 Seconds
</div>
```

"This Box will Close In 2 Seconds" will automatically change to 2sec 1sec

Answer (score 53, accepted):

use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) instead of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.settimeout), then with the combination of [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval)

```
var sec = 2
var timer = setInterval(function() { 
   $('#hideMsg span').text(sec--);
   if (sec == -1) {
      $('#hideMsg').fadeOut('fast');
      clearInterval(timer);
   } 
}, 1000);
```

html

```
<div id="hideMsg">
The entry you posted not valid.
This Box will Close In <span>2</span> Seconds
</div>
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GNrUM/)

---

**Making it better.**

```
var sec = $('#hideMsg span').text() || 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() { 
   $('#hideMsg span').text(--sec);
   if (sec == 0) {
      $('#hideMsg').fadeOut('fast');
      clearInterval(timer);
   } 
}, 1000);​
```

so that the time will depends on what is inside the `<span>`. For example, `<span>2</span>` is 2 seconds, `<span>5</span>` is 5 seconds, and `<span>60</span>` is 1 minute.

## [another crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GNrUM/2/)

Comment: @Reigel - ignore the haters - it's useful for me :) +1rep

Comment: Working great, why there is delay initially? Is it fixable? Thanks

Comment: try playing with `var sec = 2`. try it as `var sec = 3` or `var sec = 5` and see what would happen.. ;) cheers!

Comment: see also, **Making it better.** above.

Comment: To fix the delay set "sec" to be 1 less than the second count in the initial display message.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

I didn't realize how similar this was to Reigel's answer until I read his answer. Basically, the only difference is that I use **[`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)** to hide the `div` instead of the interval. Different options...

---

If you put the initial number in a `<span>` this will count down to zero from whatever that number is:

```
$(function() {

               // Number of seconds counter starts at is what's in the span
    var timer, counter = $("#hideMsg span").text();

      // Delay the fadeout counter seconds
    $('#hideMsg').delay(counter * 1000).fadeOut('fast');

      // Update countdown number every second... and count down
    timer = setInterval(function() {

        $("#hideMsg span").html(--counter);
        if (counter == 0) { clearInterval(timer)};

    }, 1000);

});​
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ruVh/)**

This makes use of jQuery's native **[`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)**, and it uses a **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)** that stops when it gets to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Do another set timeout after a second and set the .html() of the div like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#hideMsg').html('The entry you posted not valid. <br /> This Box will Close In 1 Second'); }, 1000);
```

Put them in a function and run the function onload like this:

```
<body onload="function_name()">
```

hope this helps.

Comment: this will not hide it. will it?

Comment: You will need to use both timeout's the one above will change the text and the original one will fade it out after 2 seconds? There is also ".hide()" in jquery if you wish to hide it without fading or ".toggle()" which will show and hide depending on the current state.