# Making a button that opens a website, starts a redirect countdown but only redirects when coming from a specific refer

Tags: php, html, redirect, button, countdown

Making a button that opens a website, starts a redirect countdown but only redirects when coming from a specific refer, yes that's a mouth full of words isn't it?

Here explained again:

User lands on my site (site B) from previous site A.
Here he finds a button.
User clicks the button, site C loads instantly in a new window.
Site B now checks if he came from site A and initiates a countdown to website D.

I think it's a lot to ask for, but I think it can be done!

Last few hours I looked at different options and found ways to make a countdown redirect, etc but not quite this.

I really REALLY thank you for taking the time to read this, I hope you can help!

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785029/jquery-countdown-timer and `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`..

Comment: never trust `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` it's browser set

Comment: it'd be nice if it was reliable :)

Comment: http is a stateless protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering, I end up going with HTTP REFF anyway and it did the job.