# jQuery countdown (minute:seconds) from seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, seconds, minute

In a script I use AJAX to request data from a script. The returned data is returned in JSON format. The script returns seconds and I'm searching for an easy way to generate a countdown showing minutes and seconds generated by the returned value.

For example if the script returns 90 I would need a countdown ticking each second showing: 1:30

Using the jQuery docs I only found [this](http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/) script, but it will require minutes and seconds to start the countdown from. Script called via AJAX only returns seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery countdown timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785029/jquery-countdown-timer)

Answer (score 2):

To convert number of seconds to minutes:seconds, you could use the following, where `totalSeconds` is the return from your AJAX request.

```
mins = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
secs = totalSeconds % 60;
```

Then use the script you linked above.